# How to Show different Navigation menu bar list in different oracle apex page?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to show different list in navigation menu bar in different page in oracle apex. How can I override Navigation Menu Bar?

Answer (score 1):

- go to navigation menu list entry
- go to "Conditions" section and create a condition

  - set its type to e.g. "PL/SQL Function Body returning a Boolean"
  - enter code which will use `:APP_PAGE_ID` as it lets you know which page you're currently on, and lets you decide whether to display that menu entry for that page or not. For example, to display it when you're on pages 2, 4 and 9 enter

    ```
    return :APP_PAGE_ID in (2, 4, 9);
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Gazi Salahuddin

If I were you, I would use the Authorization Schemes on each item menu.

Basically, an authorization scheme is based on roles and it will show the corresponding menu items to the corresponding users but depends on the role or roles.

For example:
Exists SQL Query

```
select count(*) from users where user = 'username' and role = 'Admin';
```

If the result of my dummy query returns data, the authorization scheme will render the component.

Tip: authorization schemes can be applied to anything in Oracle APEX.

Here is the link to the documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/providing-security-through-authorization.html#GUID-991AFE5A-48B7-4D75-9EEC-44152A2F52F6

Answer (score 0):

From ***Shared Components*** --> ***Navigation Menu*** --> ***Navigation Menu*** too

there are you'll see Authorization Scheme column like this in yellow [image]

just click on it then choose what scheme you want to apply to specific entry